# Prime number in C without using flag and break

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, if-statement, primes

I have just started learning C, and I am trying to prime number, maybe without using flag, or break, or bool?

Here i'm trying to build a program that will give me the 8th prime number and it's not running right, Im extremely uncertain about the part deciding wether or not a number is a prime number.

```
int main(void){

int i,j,th = 0;
int n = 8;

for (i=2; th <= n; i++) {
   for(j=2; j<=i; j++) {
        if(i%j !=0) {       
            th = th + 1;
            printf("%d",i);
        }
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/primality-test-set-1-introduction-and-school-method/

Comment: bool is_prime(int n) {
    if (n <= 1 || (n%2==0 || n%3==0)) return 0;
    if (n <= 3) return 1;
    for (int i = 5; i <= sqrt(n); i+=6)
        if (n%i == 0 || n%(i+2) == 0)
         return 0;
    return 1;
}

Comment: `"%d"` ->  `"%d\n"` would be a good start

Comment: @cosinus0: the fact that all primes larger than `3` are in the form `6k ± 1` is a neat trick, nice.

Comment: @YanJun, I don't see why you would impose such unnecessary restrictions, like not using a flag or `break`. Do what ever you need to solve the program. The best possible programming you can do is to write small, testable, pure (no side effects) functions, and compose your program out of them. Start by writing a function `isPrime(int)`, test it and [debug it](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). This is a 5-line program. You absolutely must learn how to use a debugger at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are too many cases that fall into the case where

```
if (i % j != 0)
```

For example, (i = 4, j = 3) but 4 is not prime. You would need to loop j from 2 to the square root of `i,` making sure that none of them are divisible.

This just seems hard without a flag (one trick you can do is to take the `(i-1)! % i == 0` for `i > 4`).

Answer (score 0):

In this for loop

```
for(j=2; j<=i; j++) {
     if(i%j !=0) {       
         th = th + 1;
         printf("%d",i);
     }
}
```

you are outputting a number as a prime number as soon as there exists the divisor `j` such that `i % j` is not equal to 0.

For example if `i` is equal to `4` (and it is not a prime number) and `j` is equal to `3` then you are outputting `4` because `4 % 3` is not equal to `0`.

Also the condition of the loop

```
for(j=2; j<=i; j++) {
         ^^^^
```

is incorrect because `i` is always divisible by itself.

The program can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );
        
        unsigned int n;
        
        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;
        
        putchar( '\n' );
        
        for ( unsigned long long i = 0; n != 0; i++ )
        {
            int prime = i % 2 == 0 ? i == 2 : i != 1;
            
            for ( unsigned long long j = 3; prime && j <= i / j; j += 2 )
            {
                prime = i % j != 0;
            }
            
            if ( prime ) 
            {
                printf( "%llu ", i );
                --n;
            }               
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 20

2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 8

2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```